# How to fresh tab after delete data from table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

When data has been deleted from DB, the tab will go back to table tab, but won't refresh. I tried reload(), but the tab jump to the home page and never stop refreshing. "(#table).table("refresh")" is not responding. 
I also tried

```
window.location = "Home.php";
```

this will refresh and jump to the home page, but if I did

```
window.location = "Home.php#SectionB";
```

this will not jump, and will also not refresh.

Can anyone help me on this? Need to refresh the tab, but stay on this tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Confirm if user want to delete the selected event from database
    function confirmDelete() {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?");
        return r;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="form-nasa-heading" align="center">Events Detail</h2>
    <form name="deleteEvent" method="post">
    <table  style="width:100%" class="detail table table-bordered" id="showevent">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        require '../others/ConnectDB.php';
        $sql = 'SELECT * from Events';
        foreach($db->query($sql) as $events)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo $desc = $events['Desc'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<button name="deleteEvent" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-remove" type="submit" onclick="return confirmDelete()"></button>';
            echo '<input name=eventId value="',$events['ID'],'"  type="hidden">';
            $eventId = $events['ID'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </table></form>
</body>
<?php
function DeleteEvent(){
    require '../others/ConnectDB.php';
    $eventId = $_POST['eventId'];
    if(isset($eventId)){
// Delete selected event from database
        $sqlDeleteEvent = "DELETE FROM Events WHERE ID= \"$eventId\"";
        $resultDeleteEvent = $db->query($sqlDeleteEvent);

// Show Success alert
        if($resultDeleteEvent) {    
            echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("You Have Delete Event Successfully!!");
            $(\'a[href="#SectionB"]\').tab(\'show\');
            $("#showevent").table("refresh");
            </script>';
        } 
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['deleteEvent'])){
    DeleteEvent();
}
?>
</html>
```

And my tab is like:

```
<div class="nav-tabs" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#SectionA">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#SectionB">Events</a></li>
</ul>
</div>     
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="SectionA">
<?php
    include_once('Welcome.html');
?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="SectionB">
<?php
    include_once('EventsPage.php');
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting you can use the header to the same page so that it will redirect to the same page.

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteEvent'])){
    DeleteEvent();
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

Comment: This will jump to the home page, not stay on the tab. As I said, I don't want it to jump.

Comment: It's not working in that way. So that's why I use             $(\'a[href="#SectionB"]\').tab(\'show\');